# Can one encapsulate Xml Rpc call within an winhttp object?

Tags: proxy, xml-rpc, winhttp

Is it possible to encapsulate an Xml Rpc call within an Winhttp 5.1 object ?
The reason I am asking this is because as far as I know Winhttp automatically resolves any proxy settings which I do not know beforehand for each user. I also don't want to set the proxy for each xml rpc call I make by hand since my users are all over the country.

Thx for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me :

```
var url = new Uri("http://www.example.com/");
string ProxyUrl = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(url).ToString();
```

Comment: I am not sure if it also handles .pac files